# I am (glad/happy) to meet you

Tags: meaning

'I am glad to meet you.'
'I am happy to meet you.'

1. I heard from somewhere that the latter is usually used by children and those who are very intimate with each other. Is it true?
2. Do you think it have any differences?

Comment: I wouldn't use either. "Pleased to meet you"  is far more common in UK.

Comment: happy, glad, pleased, "It's a pleasure to meet you"; they all work fine. I believe that "pleased" is most common in AmE as well as BrE. As for "children and people who are intimate:  children don't say any of these (unless forced to do so by overly-strict parents). And people who are "intimate" don't say such greetings either—they are beyond that stage, it would sound ludicrous.